# Applescript to extract XML tag value from a folder of files to a text file

Tags: mac, xml, applescript

I'm looking into a way to extract the values of a XML tag from a lot of file in a folder with subfolder... and save the tag value and the filename in a text file...

The value tag I need is from between `<egJob:description>` and `</egJob:description>`

In my example below, I need the `filename` with the value `250ML CLIENT (152)` like:

```
B397-000_TNW_C = 250ML CLIENT (152)
```

Here's an example of one of all my XML file:

Filename: `B397-000_TNW_C`

Content:

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 5.1.2">

   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">

      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""

            xmlns:egJob="http://test_test.com>

         <egJob:orderid>RTT1299</egJob:orderid>

         <egJob:suborderid>RTT1299</egJob:suborderid>

         <egJob:description>250ML CLIENT (152)</egJob:description>

      </rdf:Description>

   </rdf:RDF>

</x:xmpmeta>
```

So Far I try this script I found, but it won't do what I want:

```
set LeTexte to read file "Users:bob:Desktop:B397-000_TNW_C.xml"
set debut_tag to "<egJob:description>"
set end_tag to "</egJob:description>"
set debut_of_data to offsetofstart_tagintheText
set end_of_data to (offsetofend_tagintheText) + (-1 + (length of end_tag))
set theXML to textstart_of_data thru end_of_data of LeTexte
set theFile to open for access file ((path to desktop as text) & "output.xml" as text) with write permission
set eoftheFile to 0
writetheXMLtotheFilestarting at 0
close accesstheFile
```

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? We don't want to duplicate work you've already done, suggesting things you've already tried, and we also expect people to expend some effort solving things themselves. Use the EDIT button to make your question more complete.

Comment: Why do you need AppleScript?

Comment: I don't need Applescript absolutely ... If someone know a better and simpler way i'm open for any suggestion :)